# Can Socket.io be used on node.js if node.js was compiled without openssl?

Tags: node.js, express, cryptography, openssl, socket.io

I am working on a node.js project using Express and Socket.io on an embedded sheeva board (node.js 0.10.12 running on busybox Linux). Since this is embedded, everything is built with sparse options and there is no crypto stuff installed (node.js was compiled --without-openssl). This server will be used on a LAN and no sensitive information will be transmitted or received, so encryption isn't required.

When I run this script with node:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);
```

node fails with the following output:

```
tls.js:67
    throw new Error('node.js not compiled with openssl crypto support.');
Error: node.js not compiled with openssl crypto support.
    at tls.js:67:9
    at NativeModule.compile (node.js:892:5)
    at NativeModule.require (node.js:861:18)
    at https.js:22:11
    at NativeModule.compile (node.js:892:5)
    at Function.NativeModule.require (node.js:861:18)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:297:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodeserver/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:10:13)
```

This is expected since node was compiled without openssl support. Tracking down the error in `/usr/share/nodeserver/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js`, this is the line that is causing the issue:

```
https = require('https')
```

I know I can't simply comment that out. Is there some way to tell Socket.io to not use any `https` and crypto features?

I've searched around and found tons of information on how to use Socket.io *with* openssl, but nothing about how to use it *without*...

Comment: Did you try and comment out the https line? I think you should try that once. Socket.io is built such that it can support connections with both TLS or otherwise, so if you remove all the crypto stuff from Socket.io lib, then I think it should still work.

Comment: I did try that, and it just fails at the point in WebSocket.js where that object is used.

Comment: I think its due to the CommonJS standard and that conditional requir-ing is not considered good. Besides author would have thought it is best to bundle both. Providing only one seperately may not have been a good idea.

Comment: I might be missing something but... why just not use http instead of https? It doesnt work?

Comment: @Jarema IT doesn't work. Those first three lines of code that I mention will trigger the error. When I do `require('socket.io')(server)` (where `server = require('http').Server()`) it throws the error `node.js not compiled with openssl crypto support.`. The `ws` module which is required by `engine.io` which is required by `socket.io` always calls `require('https')` and `require('crypto')`.

Comment: @user568109 That makes sense. It looks like I will just have to build node.js with ssl support even if I'm not using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you change

https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocketServer.js#L10

from

```
  , crypto = require('crypto')
```

to

```
  , crypto = null
```

Since this object is only used for secure connections - not a nice solution as you are modifying an included module but it should work.

I don't think modifications are actually needed here (but on testing you might find you need to):

https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocket.js#L13
https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/WebSocket.js#L572